# Setting up alias for master branch in composer

Tags: composer-php, packaging, packagist

I am trying to package a [module](https://github.com/MisterGlass/kohana-twig) for use with composer. I have a valid composer file and I am able to install it with composer, but only when I specify that it should use dev releases (via the "@dev" version directive or minimum stability dev). I am having trouble packaging my repo so that it is seen as a master release.

I found a composer [document about aliases](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md) that seems to be made for my case, but I cant get it working. Heres the relevant portion of [my composer.json](https://github.com/MisterGlass/kohana-twig/blob/master/composer.json#L26):

```
    "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.0"
    }
}
```

Also for reference heres the require from my main projects composer file:

```
"require": {
    "misterglass/kohana-twig"  : "1.*"
},
```

And the actual error from composer is:

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package misterglass/kohana-twig 1.* could not be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to some helpful people on the #composer IRC channel, aliases are just to associate different versions to each other, and not to assign stability.

In order to for composer to consider it stable, you need to add a tag, which you can do on the [command line](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) or by [creating a release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases) in github.